# WP Query to list posts published between two particular dates

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I just want to List the posts published between two particular dates

I found a solution Here http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-loop-get-posts-published-between-two-particular-dates

and my code is Here, unfortunately This is not working !!

```
<?php
          function filter_where($where = '') {
                $where .= " AND post_date >= '2012-05-09' AND post_date <= '2012-05-11'";
                //$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
            return $where;
          }
        add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
        query_posts($query_string);
        ?>
               <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
               <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### First you shouldn't be using `query_posts()` as it will destroy globals and mess up conditionals etc...

You didn't mention where this code is running.  If it is on a page template for instance you will not get any posts because when pass $query_string into your query you are using the global $wp_query object and it will only query for page post_types.

I tested your code using new WP_Query instead of query_posts and it worked fine.

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {

$where .= " AND post_date >= '2012-05-01' AND post_date < '2012-05-14'";
return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) );

    echo '<div id="content" style="color: white!important;">';
    echo '<h1>And here are the posts……</h1>';
    while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    
    echo '<h2>'. get_the_title() .'</h2>';
    
    
    endwhile;
    echo '</div>';
    
    
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```